# Sbt nested dependsOn

Tags: scala, sbt, subproject

I have a root project that depends on a subproject1. And subproject1 depends on subproject2.
Does that imply that I Can use subproject2's source code directly in root?

```
lazy val root =
  Project(id = "root", base = file(".")).dependsOn(sub1)

lazy val sub1 =
  Project(id = "sub1").dependsOn(sub2)

lazy val sub2 =
  Project(id = "sub2")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes.**

This can easily be checked.

*build.sbt*

```
name := "sbtdemo"

version := "0.1"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.4"

lazy val root =
  Project(id = "root", base = file(".")).dependsOn(sub1)

lazy val sub1 =
  Project(id = "sub1", base = file("sub1")).dependsOn(sub2)

lazy val sub2 =
  Project(id = "sub2", base = file("sub2"))
```

*sub2/src/main/scala/App.scala*

```
object App {
  def foo() = println("foo")
}
```

*src/main/scala/Main.scala*

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    App.foo() // foo
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. From [Classpath dependencies](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html#Classpath+dependencies) by sbt:

> ```
> lazy val core = project.dependsOn(util)
> ```
>
> Now code in core can use classes from util. This also creates an ordering between the projects when compiling them; util must be updated and compiled before core can be compiled.